# ajax jQuery auto reload data when browser page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

how can i use ajax jquery to autoreload data from selected field related data to input field? it's only working when i am using `$("#id_books").change(function()`! but i want to load data when browser page refresh or on page load....

create-form.html

```
<select name="books" class="form-control" id="id_books">
  <option value="1" selected="">haxer</option>
  <option value="2">django</option>
  <option value="3">HCV</option>
  <option value="4">python</option>
  <option value="5">CBC</option>
</select>

<div class="form-group col-sm-2 text-center">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="price" id="priceData" readonly>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    $("#id_books").load(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: `http://localhost:8000/report/${id}`,
            data: { 'id': id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    $('#priceData').val(response.price);
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The `load` event happens for `window`, iframes, images, etc.  Not `select` elements or other normal page elements.

Comment: then please tell me how can i load data on page refresh. i am first time using ajax jquery.. please explain it how do you do to do this?

Comment: Put the load event binding on the `window`

Comment: how can i use `window` function in my code? please explain something?

Comment: `$('#id_books')` => `$(window)`

Comment: i am getting this error this `(index):155 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).window is not a function` when i use `.window()`

Comment: That's not the syntax I put in my comment is it?

Comment: i am using like this `$("#id_books")=> $(window)(function () {}` its getting still error...

Comment: No dude.  Literally just replace `"#id_books"` with `window`

Comment: yes i am also use like `$(window)(function () {` its still error...

Comment: `$(window).load(function () { // ... do your stuff });` or if you use jQuery >= 3 `$(window).on("load", function () { // ... do your stuff })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$(document).ready()`, which will fire on page load. e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert("Page has loaded!");
});
```

You'll most likely need to refactor your code as `$(this).val();` won't work (as 'this' is no longer '#id_books')

I've not tested the following (but it should give you an idea), try the following:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        loadData()
    });

    $("#id_books").change(function () {
        loadData()
    });

    function loadData()
    {
        var id = $("#id_books").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: `http://localhost:8000/report/${id}`,
            data: { 'id': id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    $('#priceData').val(response.price);
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```